# Switching axes for boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I am creating boxplots in R.

Using this script, I successfully made a plot of the abundance of the sample on the y-axis, and the category on the x-axis. env$FirstCategory includes a data set that marks samples as either high, low or none. The abundance is amounts per sample such as 0.0084246282 for the first row.

```
boxplot(abundance[, 2] ~ env$FirstCategory, main = "First")
```

However, I would like to reverse this and investigate the abundance on the x-axis.

I have tried this, and it did not work:

```
abu <- abundance[, 2] 
boxplot(env$FirstCategory ~ abu, main = "Abu")
```

The error reads:

```
Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response]), ...) : 
adding class "factor" to an invalid object
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to do something like this

```
boxplot(matrix(runif(100,3,9), ncol=5), horizontal=T)
```